# Fourteen-segment display using Python turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Here is my assignment: http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/summer11/V22.0002-002/assign6_summer2011.html

So far I have written the following:

```
from turtle import *

s = input(Type in a string: )

Characters = {
    ('A') : MethodA
    ('B') : MethodB
    ('C') : MethodC
    ('D') : MethodD
    ('E') : MethodE
    ('F') : MethodF
    ('G') : MethodG
    ('H') : MethodH
    ('I') : MethodI
    ('J') : MethodJ
    ('K') : MethodK

for c in s:
    c = c.upper() # to fold lowercase into upper case
    if c in Characters:
        Characters[c](width)

def top_stroke():
    forward(10)
    penup()



def MethodA (width) :
top_stroke(width)    
middle_stroke(width) 
left_stroke
right_stroke(width)

def MethodB (width) :
top_stroke(width)    
middle_stroke(width) 
left_stroke(width)
right_stroke(width)


def MethodC (width) :
top_stroke(width)    
middle_stroke(width) 
left_stroke(widt)
right_stroke(width)
```

My issue is that I am not sure how to draw each stroke. I know that I then must insert how it will draw each letter and number, but am I on the right track? Could anyone help me possibly just to draw `top_stroke` to get me started? Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [documentation for the `turtle` module](http://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html)?

Comment: Added homework tag and formatted as code.  Note that I had to do some indenting -- you should check to make sure I got it right.  Also, in `MethodA`, you have `left_stroke` -- should that be `left_stroke(width)`?

Comment: @Chris B., I hate to break it to you, but it was due August first of **last year**.  :(

Comment: Yes it should. Thanks for reformatting. I am a first time poster and brand new programmer (only about 2 weeks in). I am looking over the documentation now, thanks for the link.

Comment: Also note that you're missing a closing `}` for your Characters dictionary.

Comment: I think your first step should be to draw up a map (possibly on paper) of a single digit/letter, so you can figure out where each stroke will be in terms of (x, y) coordinates, and how many pixels/units it should take up.

Comment: Thanks Marius, I am doing that now. My big issue is actually drawing the line in turtle graphics, anything I write doesn't seem to run at all...

Comment: Better to copy the requirements here than just a link. Make it easy to help you. Links can be broken, after all.

Answer (score 0):

After six plus years, this question deserves an answer.  Sort of.  Instead of implementing the 14 segment alphanumeric display, I'll demonstrate the basic idea using a 7 seven segment (hex) digit display.  I'll use the conventions from this [seven segment display article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display).  Also, instead of *drawing* the segments, I'll define a custom turtle cursor that is a segment and *stamp* it as needed:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SCALE = 1.75  # arbitrarily scale digits larger or smaller

CURSOR_SIZE = 25  # maximum dimension of our custom turtle cursor

SPACING = CURSOR_SIZE * 1.25 * SCALE  # space from start of one digit to the next

DIGITS = {  # which segments to turn on encoded as bits
    '0': 0x7E,
    '1': 0x30,
    '2': 0x6D,
    '3': 0x79,
    '4': 0x33,
    '5': 0x5B,
    '6': 0x5F,
    '7': 0x70,
    '8': 0x7F,
    '9': 0x7B,
    'A': 0x77,
    'B': 0x1F,
    'C': 0x4E,
    'D': 0x3D,
    'E': 0x4F,
    'F': 0x47,
}

def display_number(turtle, number):
    for digit in str(number):
        bits = DIGITS[digit]

        for bit in range(7):
            if 2 ** bit & bits:
                position = turtle.position()
                segments[bit](turtle)
                turtle.stamp()
                turtle.setheading(0)
                turtle.setposition(position)

        turtle.forward(SPACING)

def segment_A(turtle):  # top
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 20 * SCALE)

def segment_B(turtle):  # right upper
    turtle.setposition(turtle.xcor() + 10 * SCALE, turtle.ycor() + 10 * SCALE)

def segment_C(turtle):  # right lower
    turtle.setposition(turtle.xcor() + 10 * SCALE, turtle.ycor() - 10 * SCALE)

def segment_D(turtle):  # bottom
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - 20 * SCALE)

def segment_E(turtle):  # left lower
    turtle.setposition(turtle.xcor() - 10 * SCALE, turtle.ycor() - 10 * SCALE)

def segment_F(turtle):  # left upper
    turtle.setposition(turtle.xcor() - 10 * SCALE, turtle.ycor() + 10 * SCALE)

def segment_G(turtle):  # center
    turtle.setheading(90)

segments = [segment_G, segment_F, segment_E, segment_D, segment_C, segment_B, segment_A]

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(950, 200)
screen.register_shape('segment', ((-12.5, 0), (-10, 2.5), (10, 2.5), (12.5, 0), (10, -2.5), (-10, -2.5)))  # <=>

turtle = Turtle('segment', visible=False)
turtle.shapesize(SCALE)
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

turtle.setx(SPACING - screen.window_width() / 2)

display_number(turtle, "0123456789ABCDEF")

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Increasing the number of segments to 14, making the text print on mutiple lines and adding a decimal point are all left as exercises for the reader.